# Save selected regions on jvectormap

Tags: vector, jvectormap

I am using jVectorMap.  [this is exact concept used in my program](http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/). please check link first.

this is my test map link (cant upload here) http://test.rst-mt.com/Screenshot.png

I want to save/hold on name of the region. it is basically ticket system where i am selecting seats(multiple select is allowed).  I want to process this with php and mysql(selected seats and pricing). so i want a way to know what i have selected so that can be read by php and i can process it.

Comment: jVectorMap lib is for country/world map. How can you use it for ticket system for selecting seats. Provide a jsfiddle and more info about you r issue.

Comment: i have attached a link of an image tht is my testing map, also we can use it i am using it here is example by jVectorMap [http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/](http://jvectormap.com/examples/mall/)